# How to check if a value exists in an array and get the next value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array `let x = ["", "comp", "myval", "view", "1"]`.

I want to check first whether or not the value `"comp"` exists in the array, and if it does then get the very next value. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  let x = ["", "comp", "myval", "view", "1"];
  if (x.indexOf(yourVal) >= 0) {

   let nextValue = x[x.indexOf(yourVal) + 1];

  } else {
   // doesn't exist.
  }
```

Note : you won't get next values if your values is last value of array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
var x=["","comp","myval","view","1"],
    l=-1!==x.indexOf("comp")?x[x.indexOf("comp")+1]:"no value";
console.log(l);
```

Comment: You are looping over array twice. Its better to save index value in one variable

Comment: I aagree with you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function and return undefined if no next value.

```js
function getNext(value, array) {
    var p = array.indexOf(value) + 1;
    if (p) {
        return array[p];
    }
}

let x = ["", "comp", "myval", "view", "1"]

console.log(getNext('comp', x));
console.log(getNext('foo', x));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = ["", "comp", "myval", "view", "1"]

let nextIndex = x.indexOf('comp') > -1 ? x.indexOf('comp') + 1 : -1;
```

basically, check if `"comp"` exists in `x`, if `true` i.e `> -1` then it returns `indexOf("comp") + 1`  which is the next item else returns `-1`

Answer (score 0):

An alternate can be to have first element as `undefined` and then fetch index of search value and return `array[index + 1]`.

Since first element is `undefined`, for any non matching case, index would return `-1`, which will fetch first element in array.

This approach involves creating new array and using `if(index) return array[index]` would be better, still this is just an alternate approach of how you can achieve this.

```js
function getNext(value, array) {
  var a = [undefined].concat(array)
  var p = a.indexOf(value) + 1;
  return a[p];
}

let x = ["", "comp", "myval", "view", "1"]

console.log(getNext('comp', x));
console.log(getNext('foo', x));
```